# Enable Tab Type inbox in Gmail

Tags: gmail, priority-inbox

[image: Screen with Gmail Inbox tabs]

Above is a screenshot from my college's computer. He does have multiple inboxes in format of Tab bar. 
See, He has switching/tabs like Classic, Important, Unread First etc.

Now, I request you to have a quick look at following snapshot from my machine.

I am just asking for enabling that kind of tabs in my Gmail.

[image: No Gmail tabs in this account]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hover over inbox & click the dropdown arrow. Howevering over Inbox type lets you try out the tab-style UI for selecting Inbox type.

[image: Inbox Type]

Comment: I can't replicate that. I don't have that link.

Comment: You have that link even after you close the tabs a second time? Because I don't see it either using the new theme or an older one, regardless of the browser I'm using.

Comment: @Alex yes, I do. I can switch between either

Comment: Could be they are testing it as a future feature.

Comment: @Alex - not sure. This is on an Google Apps account - that's the last place you'll see a future feature

Answer (score 3):

I cannot repeat for the second account, but try accessing the settings (top right, the gear wheel) at

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/inbox

Then try rolling over the inbox section

[image: Inbox section at Gmail]

Comment: @sugar the image above worked for me.

Comment: @sugar but the tabs in the picture are not different inboxes. They are simply different types to display the same inbox.

Comment: I can, refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

They are not tabs, it’s just a Google suggestion to try out new types on inbox. Once you click on the `x` (close) button from the right, there is no way back.

Comment: there is no way back ? :'( :( But for me, I didn't prompted not for a single time.

Comment: @sugar-SagarKothari - refer to my answer below. Alex, you can go back.

Comment: I can't. That link doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Sathya's image, the drop down arrow only appears when you hover over the "inbox" label.

When you click that dropdown arrow, you should see something similar to Sathya's image. Note that to the right of the dropdown menu, it says "try the tabs again." Click on that. The tabs will appear.

If you click on the 'x' to the right of these tabs, you'll have to do the process over again to get the tabs to display.

Also, you can go to mail settings (gear icon on upper right). Choose "Inbox"  on top menu. Switch from "classic view' to 'priority' or whatever you want.